# How to compute integral on calculator?

Tags: integration, calculator

[image]So i have this integral tending from 2(on top) to 1(on bottom ) of

$$\int_1^2x\ln(x^2 +3)x\,dx$$

If I turn it into $x^2\ln(x^2 +3)\,dx$, with integration by parts I get

$$\frac{16}{3}\,\ln(2) + \frac{49}{9}.$$

I was wondering, how is it possible that my TI nspire CAS does NOT recognize my integral? If I compute it, both with and without intervals, it gives me the same exact integral or a really weird equation with $\tan$ to the power of $-1.$

So I was wondering if any of you knew what could possibly be the problem. I tried typing it as the original integral, which is $x\ln(x^2 +3)x\,dx$, and also like this: $x^2\ln(x^2 +3)\,dx.$ Didn't get the answer above.

Any help would be really useful. :)

I am new here so mathjax is kind of a challenge to me... any help also on formatting the integral properly would be nice. :)

Comment: $\tan^{-1}$ denotes the arc tangent function ($\arctan$), the derivative of which is $1/(x^2+1)$, and more generally, with a scaling of the variable, $1/(x^2+a)$.

Comment: If i compute the integral on symbolab , i still get the same result as that on the calculator. It just seems off that i get a nice, simple result when doing it by hand but when i do it on the calculator i get a long, complex result

Comment: Show us your integration by parts, and we will tell you where it goes wrong. Because it does.

Comment: You can't expect a TI Nspire calculator to get you the same results as, say, Mathematica. The integration algorithms are just not as complete. Mathematica, by the way, gives you $\arctan$ functions. That is, Mathematica gives you $$\int=\frac{1}{9} \left(4+3 \sqrt{3} \pi +24 \log (7)-\log (64)-18 \sqrt{3} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right).$$

Comment: By the way, due to the $\ln(x^2+3)$ factor, you should expect a $\ln 7$ somewhere in the definite integral.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: no, the OP is wrong, and I bet the calculator is right.

Comment: I attached the image above!

Comment: This was how other users here advised me to do it...

Comment: It's wrong from the very first line. The term $+3$ was dropped. And later, transformation with the logarithm is also wrong.

Comment: What do you mean the very first +3 was dropped?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, you're certainly correct. The OP's answer approximates to $9.14123$, whereas the Mathematica answer approximates to $4.01626.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister: I mean I bet that the calculator found the indefinite integral.

Comment: Yes . Thanks for the help. I am doing another similar integral and i was wondering, is e^(-1/x) the same as 1/e^x?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Perhaps it did; I was talking more generally, explaining why a TI Nspire might fail to calculate some integral, whereas something like Mathematica would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By parts

$$\begin{align}\int x^2\log(x^2+3)\,dx&=\frac{x^3}3\log(x^2+3)-\int\frac{2x^4}{3(x^2+3)}dx\\
&=\frac{x^3}3\log(x^2+3)-\frac23\int\left(x^2-3+\frac9{x^2+3}\right)dx\\
&=\frac{x^3}3\log(x^2+3)-\frac{2x^3}{9}+2x-6\int\frac1{(\sqrt3t)^2+3}d(\sqrt3t)\\
&=\frac{x^3}3\log(x^2+3)-\frac{2x^3}{9}+2x-\frac63\sqrt3\arctan t\\
&=\frac{x^3}3\log(x^2+3)-\frac{2x^3}{9}+2x-2\sqrt3\arctan\frac x{\sqrt3}
.\end{align}$$

Comment: Can the answer be re-written without the arc tan ?

Comment: @MichaelMorello: no.

Comment: @MichaelMorello: as said, integration by parts (just like you tried).

Comment: Oh yes sure sorry i got confused... what about the second line ? there i am pretty confused. Are you expanding the integral ? where is the -2+ fraction coming from ??

Comment: @MichaelMorello: long polynomial division.

Comment: So were is my method actually wrong?

Comment: @MichaelMorello I already explained you.